# How do Emacs diary-mode and calendar-mode read so many date formats? Magic?

Tags: perl, date, emacs, calendar

The Emacs calendar mode reads a diary file (~/diary) and interprets a wide variety of formats for the date of each entry.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Date-Formats.html

I always thought it was a little bit magical that you could basically write something any number of ways and Emacs would know what it meant. Has anyone implemented this or something similar in Perl as a module? I am trying to convert about a hundred old plain text notes into a new standard format. Each note has a date[*] but in different formats. I'd like to scan for the date field, read the format and capture the month, day and year as numbers and use that for indexing. Thanks.

[*]: Often the file creation date is different from the date of the note.

Cheers,
Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/module/Date%3a%3aParse) handles a good number of a date formats pretty well. It's part of the [TimeDate](https://metacpan.org/release/TimeDate) distribution which has a lot of interesting date formatting stuff.

Comment: Thanks! Date::Parse handled two or three different date formats in my notes. It has a Y2K bug, though. Date::Parse::strptime("June 23, 2008") returns ('','','',23,6,108,''). It was kind of fun to deal with that; kind of a nostalgia trip. :)

Comment: @RyanSchram Date::Parse::strptime follows the ISO C standard and returns the number of years that has elapsed since 1900. 108 + 1900 = 2008, there is no Y2K bug :)